# Neural network for OCR (only digits)

Tags: opencv, neural-network, ocr

've been working on a neural network for an OCR to recognise digits. For the training, i used a set I got from an online course (which was taken from the MNIST database). The training values are in the range of -1.28 to 1.28 (I don't know why it's like that and this could be the source of the problem but i was struggling to obtain training sets from other places, any suggestions?).For some reason, the 'output' matrix from the predict function is the same value for all 10 entries. Basically, the Neural Network is not working..

```
void neuralNet(Mat M, Mat label, Mat test) {
//M is the training set of dimension 5000 X 400  (the image size is 20 X 20 and there are 5000 samples
        //label is 5000 X 10 , where the columns correspond to the represented number. i.e. ( if the number is 5 
         //  label[x][5]=1 and all other elements of the row are 0.
         // test has dimension 1 X 400

Mat layerSizes = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_32S); //Setting up the layers
layerSizes.put(0,0,400);
layerSizes.put(1, 0, 25);
layerSizes.put(2, 0, 10);
//Creating the Neural Network
CvANN_MLP nnet = new CvANN_MLP(layerSizes,CvANN_MLP.SIGMOID_SYM,0.6,1);
//Create criteria
TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.COUNT+TermCriteria.EPS,1000,0.000001);
//Create training parameters
CvANN_MLP_TrainParams param = new CvANN_MLP_TrainParams();
param.set_term_crit(criteria);
param.set_train_method(CvANN_MLP_TrainParams.BACKPROP);
param.set_bp_dw_scale(0.1);
param.set_bp_moment_scale(0.1);

//Training
int iter = nnet.train(M, label,new Mat(), new Mat() ,param, 0);
System.out.println("Number of iteratins: "+ iter);

System.out.println("Running test...");
Mat testOut = new Mat(1,10,CvType.CV_32FC1);

nnet.predict(test,testOut);
System.out.println(testOut.dump());
double []t = null;
System.out.println("The recognised symbols are:");
double max=0;
int loc=-1;
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    t=testOut.get(0, j);

    if(max < t[0])
    {
        max=t[0];
        loc=j;
    }
}
System.out.println(loc);    }
```

testOut.dump() results in [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] I'm very new to this, but i have a "decent" understanding of Neural network. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You can get MNIST here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ . Did you check input matrices values? Are they correct?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question actually is. Could you edit your question to clarify exactly what it is?

Comment: Sorry. Basically, my neural network is not working. I wanted to know if I had set it up correctly. Basically I had have 400 nodes in input layer, 25 in hidden layer and  10 nodes in output layer. It simply gives and output of [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0].

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
CvANN_MLP nnet = new CvANN_MLP(layerSizes,CvANN_MLP.SIGMOID_SYM,0.6,1);
```

give me an impression, that you use sigmoid. If you have input between -1.28 and 1.28 it can be quite big source of problem, because sigmoid recommended to use for values [0, 1]. You better switch from sigmoig to tanh, but also normilize your data from [-1.28, 1.28] to [-1, 1] or if you want to remain with sigmoid to [0, 1].